# Including JQuery library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have the following file organization:

Project > SubFolder1> SubFolder2> Subfolder3> Test.aspx

and I am trying to include Jquery library from

Project> Scripts

in test page I did both:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="../../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

but it gives me that the resource cannot be found and the URI in source view is:

localhost:44388/Project/SubFolder1/SubFolder2/SubFolder3/~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js

How can I include the library correctly?

Comment: you can include it in the master page, if you're using one

Comment: @WimOmbelets Though, relative paths don't *stick* to master pages, so the problem would still apply.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to include it like this

```
<script src="/Project Name/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this (without tilde):

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Or if you are in an ASP.NET MVC context:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")"></script>
```

Comment: than you but the resource still not available I have the following URI LocalHost/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping all the *javascript* files in a seperate folder in the **ROOT** folder and name it '*js*'.

For ex if your root folder is **PROJECTS**, then make a new folder '*js*' and paste all you javascript and jquery files in this folder then you can reference this files in this manner

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CDN for these kind of universally known, general purpose libraries.

A Content Delivery network gives you the advantage of faster load time, because of the clients will be served by the nearest/fastest server (less network latency), and of course, if the client already visited some other website which also made use of jQuery over the CDN, there's a big chance the file is already in the browsers cache, so no download of the file is actually needed.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

See
http://jquery.com/download/